# Getting a CC copy of user invite Emails

Tags: php

The code below works great.  It allows a user to send a recommendation for my site to a list of friends via email.

For each person that gets the email below, I would like to get an email with that person's email, and the name of the person that sent them the message.  If my email address was john@site.com, what code could I use to do this?

Thanks in advance,

John

```
$msg = "<html><body>Hello, your friend ".htmlspecialchars($_POST['sendername'])." recommends that you use <a href='http://www.site.com/'>Site.com</a>.<a href='http://www.site.com/'>Site.com</a><br><br><img src='http://site.com/images/blacklogo.PNG'></body></html>";
$subject = "Try out Site.com";
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: ' . $_POST['sendername'] . "\r\n";
foreach($_POST['email'] as $email){
mail($email, $subject,$msg,$headers);
}
```

Comment: You're open to header injection attacks on line 5. You should escape your input.

Comment: $headers= mysql_real_escape_string($headers);   ?

Comment: `str_ireplace(array("\r", "\n", "%0a", "%0d", "Content-Type:", "bcc:","to:","cc:"), "", $_POST['sendername']);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$msg = "<html><body>Hello, your friend ".htmlspecialchars($_POST['sendername'])." recommends that you use <a href='http://www.site.com/'>Site.com</a>.<a href='http://www.site.com/'>Site.com</a><br><br><img src='http://site.com/images/blacklogo.PNG'></body></html>";
$subject = "Try out Site.com";
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "CC: foo@example.com\r\n";
$headers .= "BCC: foo@example.com\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: ' . $_POST['sendername'] . "\r\n";
foreach($_POST['email'] as $email){
    mail($email, $subject,$msg,$headers);
}
```

Rather than messing about with raw headers, consider using one of the many great APIs available, like [`Swiftmailer`](http://swiftmailer.org/), [`PHPMailer`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/), or [`Zend_Mail`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.html) to name just three. `Zend_Mail` example:

```
$mail = new Zend_Mail();
$mail->setBodyHtml('<p>hello</p>');
$mail->setFrom('foo@example.com', 'foo@example.com');
$mail->setSubject('Test Subject');
$mail->addTo('foo@example.com', 'Test');
$mail->addCc('foo@example.com', 'Another Test');
$mail->addBcc('foo@example.com', 'Another Test');
$mail->send();
```

Comment: You need to add \r\n to the end of the CC and BCC lines

Comment: @karim79,  I tried your original suggestion, but it's not sending the CC to my email address.

Comment: @John - I've edited. I think the MIME needs to be the first header, and it's a good idea to have a Content-Type header too.